# Rally kanban board with only leaf stories

Tags: rally, kanban

I'd like to modify the Rally Kanban board so that it only displays leaf stories, just like the regular backlog.

If I could simply change the query so that it only returns stories without children, I'd be done.  But unfortunately, I don't see an obvious way to change the query in the config item to accomplish this, since you can't query on the "Children" attribute of user stories.

What's the easiest way to do this?  Can I post-process afterwards and easily not have it display cards that have children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be interested to see my proposed added callback/filter to accomplish this as an edit to the standard Rally App Catalog Kanban, outlined in the 2nd answer to [Filtering epics from Kanban board](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999975/filtering-epics-from-kanban-board)

Comment: That gets me very close, but unfortunately, I get an obscure type error when I display my board which has a lot of cards.   I've simplified the function passed to "addAventListner" so that it just calls `cardboard.setItems(args.items); return;` and it still fails with apparently the same type error, so I'm not sure where to take it from there...

Comment: Ok, so I noticed that setItems() was a un-documented method.  I also looked at the filtering routine and noticed that it was in fact modifying the items directly, not copies.  I figured these were probably call by reference, and this turns out to be the case, and thus the call to setItems() is actually not needed.  I just removed the call, and it works great, filtering properly!  Thanks!!!

Comment: Good catch! I edited the answer under Filtering epics from Kanban board to reflect your finding. Cheers, Mark W